Are "leave the phone for me" and "leave the phone to me" the same?
I guess "leave the phone for me" and "leave the phone to me" are different.
Look at examples from the dictionary

Did she leave a package for me?
We left a good tip for our waitress. = We left our waitress a good
tip.
I left a message (for you) on your answering machine
Leave your computer problems to the experts. [=let the experts solve
your computer problems]
That kind of decision should be left to the parents.
They left the decision (up) to me

It seems like "leave something for a person" implies that person have a benefit as he can use that thing for his own good.
and "leave something to a person" implies that thing has an issue and the person has to fix it.
That is my guess.
Are "leave the phone for me" and "leave the phone to me" the same?

Another meaning of leave something to is illustrated by Beginning learners of English should leave answering questions on ELL to native speakers. In other words, refrain from attempting a thing in deference to others. And yet another meaning is the ironic, as in Leave it to her to complain about a messy kitchen, which could mean either that she is renowned for such complaints or that she has complained despite the fact that it was she who made the mess, and that just such hypocrisy is typical of her.

My mind jumps to inheritance when I hear "leave something to a person"

Tom, like your previous question this is also quite refreshing after a long day of work. These phrases are used so commonly in everyday language that people often don't consciously think about the differences and use them naturally in conversation.
You are right,
"Leave the phone for me" implies that the phone is being left for your benefit or use.
For instance:
Did she leave a package for me?: The package is intended for you to receive and use.
I left a message (for you) on your answering machine: The message is meant for you to listen to.
While,
"Leave the phone to me" implies a sense of trust or delegation of responsibility.
Examples include:
Leave your computer problems to the experts: The experts are being entrusted with fixing the problems.
They left the decision (up) to me: The responsibility for making the decision is given to you.
